# ODE Solution Existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system
$$x'(t)=y(t)$$
$$y'(t)=-x(t)^3-(x(t)^2+y(t)^2-4)y(t).$$
How do I show that for every initial vector $(x_0, y_0)$, the solution $(x(t), y(t))$ of the system exists for all $t \geq 0$?
My first attempt was to show the quantity $x(t)^2+y(t)^2$ is monotone decreasing so the solution $(x(t), y(t))$ cannot go to $\infty$ in finite time so the solution must be defined for $t \geq 0$.

Comment: Try $x^4+2y^2$ a Lyapunov function.